# How to get the duration of key presses?

Tags: python-3.x, time, key, listener

I am trying to get the duration of a key pressed using python but my code works only for the first time and then the next key presses show the total time since the program executed.

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time

def keydet(key):
    return False

def keypress():
    def callb(key):  # what to do on key-release
        ti1 = time.time() - t

        ti2 = str(ti1)  # converting float value to string
        ti3 = ti2[0:5] # cutting the seconds ( time ) , without it , it will print like 0.233446546


        print("The key", key, "Pressed For", ti3)

        kp = key
        print(kp)

        a = time.sleep(0.0001)
        return key  # stop detecting more key-releases


    def callb1(key):  # what to do on key-press

        return False  # stop detecting more key-presses


    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=callb1) as listener1:  # setting code for listening key-press
        listener1.join()

    t = 0
    t = time.time()



    with keyboard.Listener(on_release=callb) as listener:  # setting code for listening key-release
        listener.join()


#Keypress Detector
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=keydet) as listener:
    keypress()
```

I tried googling it but couldn't find the best solution for me. I also saw some questions in this site but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how to do this, but maybe I can point you in the right direction. Have you heard of keyboard [make/break codes](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/FPGA/PS2+Keyboard+Scan+Codes)? When you hold a key down, it keeps sending data to your PC. If there's some low level way to see these, you could simply count them as a way of judging duration. Happy googling!

Comment: Thanks for that! I will surely look into that.